# View below another view and vertically centered

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my layout. I want EditText to be on top of layout and I want VideoView to be vertically centered. EditText appears fine but I see my VideoView aligned below the EditText (not vertically centered). However if I remove `android:layout_below="@+id/caption"` then my VideoView is vertically centered but if the video is of larger height then it will come on top of EditText and I don't want that. How can I adjust VideoView such that it is both vertically centered and below EditText?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:maxLength="100"
    android:hint="Hello"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/previewvideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/caption"

       />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: change height of videoview to wrap_content

Comment: @chitti even if i change to wrap_content..if the height of video is more it might come on top of edittext

Comment: If you set layout_below caption, then it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code it's helpful for you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Comment: u removed `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` ..i want videoview to appear vertically centre

Comment: Can you share image or wireframe what you want exact?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinearLayout` as the root `ViewGroup` and specify the `layout_gravity` for the `VideoView` with a vertical `orientation`. This will place the items top to bottom as they are ordered in the layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    ...
>
    <EditText
        .../>
    <VideoView
        ...
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:maxLength="100"
        android:hint="Hello"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/previewvideo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/caption"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding `layout_below` invalidates `layout_centerVertical`. Instead make the `EditText` use `android:layout_above="@+id/previewvideo"` and remove the `layout_below` on the VideoView.

You may have to tweak it a little more but that should get you started.

Comment: then `EditText` doesn't appear on top.. android:layout_alignParentTop="true" invalidates

Comment: then move the alignParentTop?